# Average Rating PHP

Tags: php, rating, rate

I structured a PHP table with two columns: 1 for the `hospital Id` and 1 for the `rating`.

When a user rates the page, in the Id section goes a default id (depending on the page) and the rating goes in the rating section obv.

Now, how can I calculate the average rating only for a certain ID?

I've never studied Php so I need some help! Thanks everyone!!

Comment: You did not mention what database you are using, but I guess MySql? Have a look at [AVG()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg) function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AVG` on `rating` column and `GROUP BY` on `hotel_id` column.
Can refer below query.

```
SELECT hotel_id, avg(rating) 
FROM hotel_rating
GROUP BY hotel_id;
```

PS: This is sample query you need to substitute your column names and table names in that

Comment: Ok, but what will this return? As I said, I have no exp with PHP. Will it return an array where I can put the id number as an index? For example, how can I group the values only for the id_number 1?

Comment: it will be helpful if you can paste your sample php code in the forum then will be able to determine what will get fetched from the database.
As far as `id_number = 1` is concerned use can use `SELECT hotel_id, avg(rating) 
FROM hotel_rating
WHERE hotel_id = 1
GROUP BY hotel_id;`